# Wrapping content with <div> tag after the first child <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to wrap  tag after the first child `<div>`

This is the html:

```
<details>
  <div class="first-child">Copyright 1999-2014.</div>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

I Need the output like this:

```
<details>
     <div class="first-child">Copyright 1999-2014.</div>
     <div class="details_content">
       <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
       <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
     </div>
</details>
```

This is my Attempt: But, this is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum=$('.first-child').html();
    $('.first-child').remove();
    $('details').wrapInner('<div class="details_content"></div>');
    $('<div class="first-child">' + sum +'</div>').appendTo($('details'));
    $('.details_content').hide();
    $('.first-child').click(function(){
        $('.details_content').slideToggle(0);   
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w98z0dwo/1/)

The tag `<div class="first-child">Copyright 1999-2014.</div>` is generated at the last of the `<details>` tag. I want to generate this as a first-child `<div>`.

**Also, is there any optimize solution available? Rather than writing this much of code?**

Answer (score 2):

To wrap all p element inside details, you can do like this:

```
$('details p').wrapAll('<div class="details_content" />');
```

---

With your code, that you want .first-child div to be the first-child not last, you should use prepend instead of append:

```
$('<div class="first-child">' + sum +'</div>').prependTo($('details'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("details").append('<div class="details_content"></div>');
    $("details p").appendTo(".details_content");


    $('.details_content').hide();
    $('.first-child').click(function(){
        $('.details_content').slideToggle(0);   
    });
});
```

...this should do the work in the shortest way

[[forked Fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/51hnemc8/1/)

[EDIT]: okay, Bhojendra Sah's code is one line less ;)